# What is the purpose of the Expression-manipulation tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

For what should we use the [expression-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression-manipulation) tag? It doesn't have a wiki, though from the 13 questions it seems like it covers structural manipulation of expressions. While 13 questions are not too much, there is another side of the coin: structural manipulation is a **very** important part of *Mathematica*, and is underrepresented among the tags. We always fall back to use such low-level manipulation whenever regular evaluation is not enough, and we all like the beauty of the [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/89) and the [T&S method](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/Links/index_lnk_30.html).

The topic is only partly covered by [evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation) and [replacement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replacement), which are not directly about structural manipulation. Furthermore, there is the [simplifying-expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplifying-expressions) tag: it seems like that [expression-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression-manipulation) is used whenever the other is used in a somewhat interchangeable fashion. Now I understand, that for example [rearranging knowns and unknowns in an equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13619/89) both involves algebraic and structural manipulation in *Mathematica*, but since there is no wiki for the latter, the appropriate tag lingers there without any meaning.

I would like to hear your opinion about this issue before submitting anything to the tag wiki, or before pushing for tag removal, retagging, synonymizing, or whatnot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my proposal for the tag wiki about structural manipulation:

> How to manipulate expressions structurally. The tag
>   [expression-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression-manipulation) is not about manipulating mathematical
>   formulae algebraically but is about adding/removing/replacing parts of
>   expressions structurally, often without evaluating (parts of) the
>   expression. Structural manipulation usually involves functions of the
>   `Hold` family (`Hold`, `HoldForm`, `HoldComplete`, `HoldPattern`),
>   controlled evaluation (`Unevaluated`, `Evaluate`, `ReleaseHold`) and replacement functions (`With`, `Replace`, `ReplaceAll`, etc.).

Please upvote **only**, if you think that the [expression-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression-manipulation) tag should be emended to cover this topic, and should be clearly distinguished from [simplifying-expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplifying-expressions) and [algebraic-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-manipulation).

Comment: Sounds good to me, with one (two?) minor exceptions: since `HoldForm` and `Defer` are mainly for producing held output and not often used for more general manipulations, I think questions concerning these would be better off categorized under [tag:evaluation] rather than lumped in here. `With`, on the other hand, is a very powerful tool for [tag:expression-manipulation].

Comment: @Oleks Thanks for the extra bits, I've edited my answer. But I would like to point out that `HoldForm` can be used just like `Hold` to make structural changes using `With`, see e.g. my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13943/89).